# How to connect a cordova project to database?

Tags: angular, cordova, laravel-5

I use Cordova to develop a mobile application.So, I convert my angular4 project to android using Cordova and i try the apk file in my phone it's work the  problem i get no connection with my database so how i can solove it .I use laravel as backend.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What happens when you try to connect from your current app?

Comment: when for example i try to get information from database i don't get any thing

Comment: when for example i try to get information from database i don't get any thing

Comment: You should get some sort of result, either an error message, network error, etc. We also should be able to see the code that is the source of the problem. It might help to review how to ask a good question on stack overflow, we simply don't have the information to help you with what you have provided.  [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access the database from your cordova app.

What you should do is call a webservice on your laravel backend runing on a server.

So the app on the phone calls the webservice on the server using ajax and the webservice connects to the database using php.

If your problem is that you're calling a webservice and it doesn't work, you should explain that and not just say you're trying to connect a database and it does not work.